# How to embed xml into swc file

Tags: apache-flex, swc

How can i embed and then read a xml file from and into a .swc file?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
http://dispatchevent.org/roger/embed-almost-anything-in-your-swf/

It is not a very clear post, but give it some patience..

I haven't tried it personally, but people got it worked (source: comments on the same page)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mx:XML or mx:Model tags to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
this could help your:
[Embed(source="path/to/your/xml/file",mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
public var _xml:Class;

var needXml:XML = XML(new _xml);
```